# How to fix this HtmlUnit test giving errors

Tags: javascript, java, htmlunit, htmlunit-driver

I have a HtmlUnit test on the attached code. When I run the code I get the following error:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getByXPath
```

returns a list - you can't cast this to a button. You have to take one element from the list (e.g. the first one) for casting.

Or use

```
getFirstByXPath
```